# Connection trac with svn

Tags: svn, trac

I am trying to connect Trac with svn. 
I would like to make a link in trac ticket while committing so if I am working with ticket #3 then `svn commit -m "RE #3"` should automatically appear in ticket.

Actually when I make commit it's going into repository but it doesn't appear in Ticket #3 on Trac.
Part of my `trac.ini`:

```
[repositories]
.alias = main
main.description = G�^�ówne repozytorium
main.dir = /home/svn/vlex_repo
main.hidden = true
main.type = svn
```

I also have:

```
[components]
tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.committicketreferencemacro = enabled
tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.committicketupdater = enabled
```

What should I add in `trac.ini` to make it usable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [CommitTicketUpdater](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater) page.

Which Trac version are you running? You probably need to disable per-request synchronization and enable explicit synchronization.

- [Explicit synchronization for Trac 1.2](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#ExplicitSync)
- [Explicit synchronization for Trac 1.0](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/1.0/TracRepositoryAdmin#ExplicitSync)
- [Explicit synchronization for Trac 0.12](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/0.12/TracRepositoryAdmin#ExplicitSync)

Comment: I use version 0.12 but it should also work on this dinosaur because I have the same configuration on other server.

Comment: I've updated the answer with documentation for Trac 0.12. Trac 0.12 configuration changes are the same as what's need for Trac 1.0. Trac 1.2 had some changes and needs to be handled differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot, documentation says it all. I forgot to change /hooks!